# Hide printer in Windows 7 but able to print programatically

Tags: windows-7, printer

I would like to achieve the following requirement on Windows 7 with **Guest** Account

1. The user will **not be able to see/select** a particular printer while printing with eg : Microsoft Word, Adobe Reader, etc.
2. However, the user is **allowed to print** with that hidden printer with my own developed application. ( Which means the application itself will be able to send data to the hidden printer for printing )

One approach I'm thinking is to disable the **"Print" permission** for that guest account. The printer will be hidden from the user, but that doesn't permit the user to print.

May I know is there anyway to achieve this? Either programatically or with configuration.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to achieve this? It seems odd to want this.

Comment: @LPChip What I'm trying to do is the user can only select a printer in Microsoft Word, Adobe Reader, etc. By selecting that printer ( a virtual ) it counts the number of pages the user is printing, to restrict some printing settings (Color, Black White), etc. 

After that, the virtual printer itself will send to a physical printer to print. Basically I want to gain control over what the user is printing.

Comment: There is no "easy" way (says Microsoft) to hide devices http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2018577

Comment: you know there are products out there that already do this

Comment: @Keltari may I know what's the product name? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing printer to print from selected application may be tricky. There is no such mechanism in Windows, but you can workaround this somehow. I have some **dirty idea**, you can think more about it and maybe you will figure out something better or less complex.

You can manage printer permissions, including local printers in Windows (since Windows 2000).

**I. Block print permissions for guest** (or guests group or other user supposed to use your program) - to disable normal printing for that account/group.

1. Go to Devices in printers (in Control Panel)
2. Right click printer and select "Printer Properties" (not just "Properties"!)
3. There should be Security tab. You can manage permissions for accounts and groups.
4. Configure permissions for your Guest account (or Guests group, it's up to you).

**II. Prepare system and your application to print as another user**

1. Add additional Windows account and allow it to print. You may want to disable normal logon for it (I think removing that user from Users group will prevent that user from showing up on logon screen).
2. Share your printer (normally, like for network)
3. In your application - use function apropriate for your programming language that executes commandline commands. For .NET that could be System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string Command), in Python os.system(cmd) etc.

   net use \\localhost\printer_share_name /u:nonguestaccountname nonguestaccountpassowrd"

   This will map your printer as other user (hopefully - instantly), by using `nonguestaccountname` account permission to print (print will be done as other user we created earlier).
4. You may have to wait until printer mapping is done before you try to print, make some error handling etc.
5. Handle your printing in appplication
6. Execute:

   net use \\localhost\printer_share_name /delete

   This will unmap your printer (hopefully - instantly).

Whole thing should take less than a second - while that time user could print from any application, there is a **hole in my idea**, but normal users probably will not figure out what is going on and it should be enough to save paper/ink/toners in company or something :)

With network printer - that could be unreliable, slow and could depend on LAN network quality/load, but if you map local printer like network printer - it should work very fast.

As I wrote earlier - this is very dirty method but I didn't figured out any other method than temporary printer mapping as another user. This is not 100% reliable and secure, but for some purposes you can use it.

Everything I wrote above is possible to automate with CMD or VBS scripts in your application installer.

**ANOTHER METHOD** could be executing share/unshare printer, but you need additional Windows Account anyway.

Extra tips:

[Sharing printer from command line](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e28cd16a-2681-4b31-8917-7ec7f878e10f/how-do-i-share-a-printer-on-windows-7-from-the-command-line-printer-is-added-by-ip?forum=winserverprint)

(replace en-US in path for your locale if you are not using english windows)

Edit:

You may have to test this on Vista Basic and XP Home edition, they may have simplified permission control interface and some features are hidden (I remember that some simplified windows edition have no "Security" tab or something like that).

Comment: The approach sounds doable! Hopefully it will help me to solving this major obstacle.